# 500 errors just after touching wsgi (Apache mod_wsgi and Django)

Tags: python, django, apache, error-handling, wsgi

To reload my source code after an edit i touch the wsgi in production.

This seems to cause a few 500 errors return when i reload the site, just after the touch. Everything then goes well.

I use mod_wsgi in daemon mode, and i've read [this](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/ReloadingSourceCode), in which is described that is not needed to restart apache to reload sources, just a touch will be sufficient.

Here are the relevant error.log part https://gist.github.com/apelliciari/5639266

My WSGI configuration in the virtual host (only the wsgi part)

```
WSGIDaemonProcess foo.com.djangoserver processes=5 threads=30 display-name=%{GROUP}-live
WSGIProcessGroup foo.com.djangoserver
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/vhosts/foo.com/foo/wsgi.py
```

Other useful informations:

- The 500 error is my custom 500 template, because now i've set ErrorDocument 500 in the virtual host conf
- I've set DEBUG = True but it shows always the error above
- There are no errors in the apache error log, neither i've got django error admin mails, and there's nothing on sentry too

The same happens if i reload the apache service.

**what can be my next move to sort out why it behaves in this way?**

UPDATE:

I've set Apache ErrorDocument for 500 and 404 pointing to my 500 template and it works.. and i'm not finding where the problem is, because in the logs there aren't traces of errors.

Comment: The 500 error is likely coming from Django. Setup emailing of the details of errors for unhandled exceptions in Django, that or setup Django to log them. IOW, you need to work out what the cause is. Also explain whether it is a Django error page or an Apache one. When you have details, add them to your question.

Comment: There aren't seem to be any 500 errors in the gist you posted.  Those are all normal info statements that come from the processes restarting.  You'd need to post the actual errors and tracebacks for us to help (change settings.py so DEBUG=True if you're not on a production system).